# How Do I Write A Script For Custom Installer Or Advanced Installer

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

How do i write a script for custom installer or advanced installer.

I mean i have an .exe package installed on my windows servers.
I use that for modifying some thing but i do not want to click it and open.
I want to write scripts which executes and modifies the parameter. Should change the things without manual intervention.
Somebody can help me???

The following package has been installed on servers, 
C:\Program Files\Fujitsu\ServerView Suite\Agents\Maintenance Tools\system config .exe

This is an fujitsu software/package for remote board configurations.

Here, i would like to write a script(ps or vbs) to execute .exe and change the configurations parameter. 
I cannot do this manual stuff on all the servers.

Could you please suggest me the installer?

regards,
Dharanesh,

Answer (score 0):

You should determine, which configuration way is supported by your software. Basically, there is 4 main directions. Powershell can help with

1) Configuration via command line parameters

```
$Command = "C:\Program Files\Fujitsu\ServerView Suite\Agents\Maintenance Tools\system config.exe -someconfigparameters"
cmd.exe /c $Command
```

2) Configuration via windows registry

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Fujitsu\Suite\SomeConfigKeys -Name SomeKey -Value 123 -Type DWord
```

3) Configuration via config-file without encryption

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Name some.cfg -Path C:\Program Files\Fujitsu\ServerView Suite\Agents\Maintenance Tools\ -Force
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\Program Files\Fujitsu\ServerView Suite\Agents\Maintenance Tools\some.cfg"
$stream.WriteLine("
some text config
")
$stream.close()
```

Powershell can't help with

4) Just manual configuration (no luck)